# Swift 2.2 selector in NSMenuItem

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsmenuitem, nsstatusbar

I have a simple one file menu bar app in swift:

```
import Cocoa

class StatusBarApp : NSObject {

  func buildMenu() {
    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)
    statusItem.title = "StatusBarApp"

    let menu = NSMenu()

    let aboutMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
    aboutMenuItem.title = "About"
    aboutMenuItem.target = self
    aboutMenuItem.action = #selector(about)
    menu.addItem(aboutMenuItem)

    statusItem.menu = menu
  }

  func about() {
    print("XXX")
  }
}

NSApplication.sharedApplication()
StatusBarApp().buildMenu()
NSApp.run()
```

I can't make the "About" menu bar item to connected to the about() function. When I run the app, the "About" item is disabled.

How do I pass the selector to menu item action in Swift 2.2? Thanks

Comment: In Swift 4.2, you just need to add `@objc` `func about`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector is supposed to have a parameter (the `NSMenuItem` instance)

```
aboutMenuItem.action = #selector(StatusBarApp.about(_:))

...

func about(sender : NSMenuItem) {
   print("XXX")
}
```

**Edit:**

The solution is to run the app as full Cocoa app including its delegate.
I added a second menu item to terminate the app.

```
import Cocoa

class StatusBarApp : NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

  var statusItem : NSStatusItem!

  func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)
    statusItem.title = "StatusBarApp"

    let menu = NSMenu()

    let aboutMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title:"About", action:#selector(StatusBarApp.about(_:)), keyEquivalent:"")
    aboutMenuItem.target = self
    let quitMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title:"Quit", action:#selector(StatusBarApp.quit(_:)), keyEquivalent:"")
    quitMenuItem.target = self
    menu.addItem(aboutMenuItem)
    menu.addItem(quitMenuItem)

    statusItem.menu = menu
  }

  func about(sender : NSMenuItem) {
    print("XXX")
  }

  func quit(sender : NSMenuItem) {
    NSApp.terminate(self)
  }
}

NSApplication.sharedApplication()
let statusBarApp = StatusBarApp()
NSApp.delegate = statusBarApp
NSApp.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this change, but it didn't have any affect. The item was still disabled. If I enabled it with `menu.autoenablesItems = false`, the about function was not executed.

Comment: I edited the answer. Thanks for pointing out the idea to run an application from a simple Swift file

Comment: Thank you! I was inspired by this: http://czak.pl/2015/09/23/single-file-cocoa-app-with-swift.html

Comment: I read this article, too, to find out how to handle the Swift file

Comment: One thing to note is that whatever the target is. **It needs to be referenced strongly somewhere.** If the object is not in memory, it can not be referenced and therefore can not be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

update action

```
aboutMenuItem.action = Selector("about")
```

and add

```
aboutMenuItem.enabled = true
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work. It shows a warning:
`warning: use '#selector' instead of explicitly constructing a 'Selector'`

But more importantly, the item is still disabled, even after adding `aboutMenuItem.enabled = true`

Comment: `aboutMenuItem.enabled = true` has no effect in this case, because the implicit validation has a higher priority.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this:

```
import Cocoa

class StatusBarApp : NSObject {

    func buildMenu() {
        let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(NSVariableStatusItemLength)
        statusItem.title = "StatusBarApp"

        let menu = NSMenu()

        let aboutMenuItem = NSMenuItem()
        aboutMenuItem.title = "About"
        aboutMenuItem.target = self
        aboutMenuItem.action = #selector(about)
        menu.addItem(aboutMenuItem)

        statusItem.menu = menu
    }

    func about() {
        print("XXX")
    }
}


let app = StatusBarApp()
NSApplication.sharedApplication()
app.buildMenu()
NSApp.run()
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes the "About" item enabled, but clicking on it doesn't execute the about function.

Comment: I have updated the answer. That works fine for me. Apparently the reason is memory management. I logged deinit of StatusBarApp object and identified that the app object is destructed immediately in your case.

Comment: Thank you! I already selected a different answer with different solution, but this also works.

Comment: Welcome :) @vadian It makes sense to point out that app delegate setting does not matter. The root cause is in memory management.